# Only a single emit being received from list of child components mounted() function (Vue.js 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

As briefly as I can put it, I have a main `<App />` component that houses a `<CommentList />` component.

The `<CommentList />` contains a number of `<Comment />` components, more of which are added dynamically.

In my `<App />` I have a listener for when a comment is added like so:

```
// App.vue
mounted() {
    this.$on('comment-added', console.log('wow'))
}
```

and the event is emitted from the `<Comment />` component (grand child, if that matters?)

```
// Comment.vue
mounted() {
    console.log('this works for each comment no problem')
    this.$emit('comment-added') // this only ever works 1 time
}
```

The problem is the listener in the `<App />` mounted function is only ever called once, even after subsequent comments are added to the list.

I don't understand why, any ideas? Been looking through the docs and searching but can't find any reason why this is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to indicate a method from `methods` section instead of `console.log`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [inject/provide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection) to make interaction between grandparent and grandchild component

App.vue

```
provide(){
return {
    addComment: this.addComment
  }
},
methods:{
    addComment(){
     console.log('wow')
   }
}
```

```
// Comment.vue

inject:['addComment'],
mounted() {
   this.addComment()
 
}
```